LINQ group with list inside shows only the first row
I have a view in the v_PortalProprietario database that returns in each line the name of the owners that are repeated and the accounts (Acertos) that are unique. I would like to make a query in Linq that groups the owner's data into a DTO and a property with all the accounts referring to that owner.
Running the query shown below is returning only the first Acerto in the list, but in database executing the view I have a lot of rows with the same Proprietario.
var prop = (from p in db.v_PortalProprietario
            where p.ProprietarioId == pProprietario
            group p by new {p.ProprietarioId, p.ProprietarioNm, p.Documento}
            into gp
            select new ProprietarioDTO ()
            {
                ProprietarioId = gp.Key.ProprietarioId,
                ProprietarioNm = gp.Key.ProprietarioNm,
                Documento = gp.Key.Documento,
                Acertos = gp.OrderByDescending(f => f.DataAcerto)
                                    .Select(a => new AcertoDTO
                                    {
                                        AcertoId = a.AcertoId,
                                        DataAcerto = a.DataAcerto,
                                        FormaPagto = a.FormaPagto,
                                        ValorAcerto = a.ValorAcerto,
                                        FlagConsolidacao = a.FlagConsolidacao
                                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

If I break in 2 blocks of code it works, but I want to understand why the only one doesn't work.
This works:
var itens = (from p in db.v_PortalProprietario
             where p.ProprietarioId == pProprietario
             select p);

var prop2 = itens.GroupBy(p => new { p.ProprietarioId, p.ProprietarioNm, p.Documento })
                 .Select(gp => new ProprietarioDTO
                 {
                     ProprietarioId = gp.Key.ProprietarioId,
                     ProprietarioNm = gp.Key.ProprietarioNm,
                     Documento = gp.Key.Documento,
                     Acertos = gp.Select(a => new AcertoDTO
                     {
                         AcertoId = a.AcertoId,
                         DataAcerto = a.DataAcerto,
                         FormaPagto = a.FormaPagto,
                         ValorAcerto = a.ValorAcerto,
                         FlagConsolidacao = a.FlagConsolidacao
                     }).OrderByDescending(a => a.DataAcerto).ToList()
                 }).ToList();


What RDBMS, and what SQL does the first query produce? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#simple-logging
Add it to your question.

Grouping and collecting grouping items on the server side has no sense. SQL just do not support that and EF is trying to emulate with Eager Loading. It is very ineffective SQL. Just select all needed fields without grouping and then group flat list on the client side.

Apart from the difference in placement of the ordering, both queries are not essentially different. I don't see a reason why EF would return only 1 Acerto if there are more. Compare the generated SQL of both LINQ queries. They should be identical.

The reason the second code block isn't working is that you are using the gp.OrderByDescending(f => f.DataAcerto) inside the Acertos property of ProprietarioDTO, which is causing the query to fail.
I would suggest something like this:
var prop = (from p in db.v_PortalProprietario
        where p.ProprietarioId == pProprietario
        group p by new { p.ProprietarioId, p.ProprietarioNm, p.Documento }
        into gp
        select new ProprietarioDTO
        {
            ProprietarioId = gp.Key.ProprietarioId,
            ProprietarioNm = gp.Key.ProprietarioNm,
            Documento = gp.Key.Documento,
            Acertos = gp.Select(a => new AcertoDTO
            {
                AcertoId = a.AcertoId,
                DataAcerto = a.DataAcerto,
                FormaPagto = a.FormaPagto,
                ValorAcerto = a.ValorAcerto,
                FlagConsolidacao = a.FlagConsolidacao
            }).OrderByDescending(a => a.DataAcerto).ToList()
        }).ToList();

